# Difference between datastore garbage collection in AEM and java garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, aem

Following in our Java configuration for AEM application.

```
java -server -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XXermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=<path>/tmp -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=<path>/crx-quickstart/logs/heap_dump.hprof -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:<path>/crx-quickstart/logs/gc.log -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=<path>/management/management.properties -Dsling.run.modes=author,crx3,crx3tar -Dorg.apache.felix.http.host=<ip-address> -jar crx-quickstart/app/cq-quickstart-6.1.0-standalone-quickstart.jar start -c crx-quickstart -i launchpad -nofork -p 40601 -a <ip-address> -Dsling.properties=conf/sling.properties
```

Whenever we try to build the dam asset backup package the AEM servers hangs and pages are not available for a while. After a while, server comes up by itself. We have noticed a sudden spike in size of GC logs. Not sure if they are correlated. And also what is the difference between datastore garbage collection and Java Garbage collection?

Answer (score 1):

**AEM GC**

When a conventional WCM asset is removed, the reference to the underlying datastore record may be removed from the node hierarchy, but the datastore record itself remains. This unreferenced datastore record then becomes "garbage" that need not be retained.

AEM uses the repository as the storage for a number of internal and housekeeping activities:

1. packages built and downloaded
2. temporary files created for publish replication
3. workflow payloads
4. assets created temporarily during DAM rendering

When any of these temporary objects is large enough to require storage in the datastore, and when the object eventually passes out of use, the datastore record itself remains as "garbage".

Example:

When it comes the for packages. Package data, like everything else, is stored in the repository and thus for packages which are larger than 4KB, in the datastore. In the course of a development project or over time while maintaining a system, packages may be built and rebuilt many times, each build resulting in a new datastore record, orphaning the previous build's record.

> **we have to remember below points that**
>
> 1. "garbage collections take time and may impact performance, so they should be planned accordingly"
> 2. "removal of garbage records does not affect normal performance, so this is not a performance optimization"

The garbage collector first makes a note of the current timestamp when the process begins. The GC is then carried out using a multi-pass mark/sweep pattern algorithm.

**In the first phase**, the garbage collector performs a comprehensive traversal of all of the repository content. For each content object that has a reference to a datastore record, it located the file in the filesystem, performing a metadata update -- modifying the "last modified" or MTIME attribute. At this point files that are accessed by this phase become newer than the initial baseline timestamp.

**In the second phase,** the garbage collector traverses the physical directory structure of the datastore in much the same way as a "find". It examined the "last modified" or MTIME attribute of the file and makes the following determination:

- if the MTIME is newer than the initial baseline timestamp, the record is taken to be active and the file shall not be deleted.
- if the MTIME is prior to the initial baseline timestamp, considered for removable garbage.

*MTIME = file modify time*

> This approach works well for a single node with a private datastore.
>   Shared datastore needed different approach for the GC.

For more information you can find the below Adobe documentation. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/operations/data-store-garbage-collection.html

**JAVA Garbage collection :** http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html